# explicit expression for the solution of a lower-triangular Toeplitz linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find an explicit expression for $c_k$ ($k=0,1,2,\cdots$) in terms of $A_m$ ($m=0,1,2,\cdots$) and $b_n$ ($n=0,1,2,\cdots$)from the following lower-triangular Toeplitz linear system of equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\ A_1 & A_0 & 0 &  \\  A_2 & A_1 & A_0 &  \\  \cdots &  &  & \cdots\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c_0  \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \cdots \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \cdots \end{pmatrix}$$

For example:

$$c_0=\frac{b_0}{A_0}$$

$$c_1=\frac{A_0 b_1+A_1 b_0}{A_0^2}$$

Thanks-
mike

Comment: and what is the math symbol for vertical dots?

Comment: it is \vdots try also \cdots \hdots \ddots